# Propagating onPositionChanged events to background items in QtQuick 1.1

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qt4.8

**Background.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
    MouseArea {
        id: backgroundMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onPositionChanged: {
            console.log("Background")
        }
    }
}
```

**Foreground.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
    Background {
        width: 1920
        height: 1080
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onPositionChanged: {
            console.log("Foreground")
            [mouse.accepted = false] - Not working (as the docs say)
            [backgroundMouseArea.onPositionChanged(mouse)] - Not working
        }
    }
}
```

I need to execute `onPositionChanged` event on both background and foreground items.

F.ex. for `onPressed` I would do it by setting `mouse.accepted = false` in the foreground item.

Can I call `onPositionChanged` of the background item manually? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve here.
A `MouseArea` is meant to grab mouse events from hardware. If you really want to propagate mouse events to background from a different `MouseArea`, maybe what you actually want to do is give `Background` a simple `property mousePosition` instead of the `MouseArea`, and then set that position from the Foreground `onPositionChanged` handler.

Also, your Foreground code relies on an internal `id` parameter inside of Background. This smells really bad. It is often more useful to think about the "Public API" of the Background and Foreground "classes". If what I described above is really what you want to do, this is what it should look like IMHO:

```
// Background.qml
import QtQuick 1.1
Rectangle {
    // an object with just x and y properties
    // or the complete mouseevent, whatever you want
    // Use variant for QtQuick 1/Qt4, var for QtQuick 2.0 / Qt5
    property variant mousePosition
    onMousePositionChanged: console.log(
      "Background " + mousePosition.x + " " + mousePosition.y
    )
}

//Foreground.qml
import QtQuick 1.1
Item {
  // use only ids defined in the same file
  // else, someone might change it and not know you use it
  Background { id: background }
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    hoverEnabled: true

    onPositionChanged: {
       console.log("Foreground")
       background.mousePosition = {x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y}
    }
  }
}
```

...........